# How to use search for a calculating column in Spotfire

Tags: case, spotfire, case-when

I want to create a calculated column from an existing column for filtering. I am linking the unique values using case statement and it just works with the existing values and it cannot include the search parameters. If i cant do a */% or any type of search i cant include for different variation of the column values that may come in the future. So need to search and substitute through the inbuilt Spotfire functions

**My Current Code:**

```
Case  
when [column]=  "Point" then "Value1" 
else "Value2"
end
```

**How I want,but not working cos its not accepting normal search parameters:**

```
  Case  
    when [column] like "%Poi%" then "Value1" 
    else "Value2"
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use that SQL syntax in spotfire. Use `~=` or `RxReplace`.

```
if([column] ~= "Poi+","Value1","Value2")
```

Or...

```
case
   when [column] ~= "Poi+" then "Value1"
   else "Value2"
end
```